# HTML5 - Padding Main Section/Two Column Setup

Tags: css, html

I have been racking my brain for 3 and a half hours trying to do 2, seemingly, simple tasks. First task is to pad the outside of paragraph div and the other is to split the main section into two columns so I can add some links to other parts of the website. Below is my code if you know what I can do to solve my dilemma, please leave a comment below.

Thank you.

```css
html {
 font-family: Segoe, Segoe UI, DejaVu Sans, Trebuchet MS, Verdana," sans-serif";
 font-size: 120%;
}
header {
 background-color: #6699cc;
 margin: auto;
 background: no-repeat center center cover;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 60%;
 height: 114px;
 border: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav {
 background-color: none;
 border: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 50px;
}
#header-left { 
 width: 50%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
   height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
   left: 55px;
 z-index: 2;
}
#header-right {
 width: 50%;
    display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
   height: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
}
nav li {
 float: left;
 border-left: 1px solid #555;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 align: bottom;
}
#banner-img {
    width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.5;
}    
body {
 margin: 0;
}
main h1, h6 {
 margin: 0 0 0 37.3%;
    padding-left: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
 background-color: #6699cc;
}
main h6 {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: medium solid #555555;
}
main {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 60%;
}
.TextWrap {
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
}
h1.featured { color: #FFFFFF}
span.article { color: #444}
footer { 
 background-color: #555; 
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf 8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="techworldtoday.css" />
</head>
<header>
 <div id="banner">
     <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="container">
    <a HREF="http://www.techworldtoday.net"><img class="banner-img" src="images/logobackground1.png" alt="Tech News Today"/></a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="header-left">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tech World Today" align="bottom"/>
 </div>
 <div id="header-right">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" id="page1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html" id="page2">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="benchmarks.html" id="page3">Benchmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="tutorials.html" id="page4">Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="tutorials.html" id="page5">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="tutorials.html" id="page6">About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav> 
 </div>
</header>
<body background="images/techbackground.png" bgcolor="#333">
</body>
<main>
 <div id="paragraph">
  <img class="element" src="images/cybermonday.png" alt="Cyber Monday" height="290" width="400" />
  <h1 class="featured">Cyber Monday <span class="article">2016</span></h1>
  <h6>By Gregory Shepherd</h6>
  <p>Technology companies broke records during this holidays “Cyber Monday” shopping event with almost 3.5 billion dollars spent worldwide. This beat sales for the previous year by over 12%. Analysts show a massive swing toward online sales and even claim that Black Friday 2017 could be the top online shopping day of the year. After making deals available earlier this year, companies have shown that starting Cyber Monday with deals early wouldn’t hurt sales. If this trend continues we may see deals spring up as early as the first of November 2017.</p>
  <p>This year’s record breaking sales were due companies offering more products online for pick up than were available in previous years. Target collaborated with the Curbside app to allow customer to purchase items from their mobile devices and pick the items up in store. Amazon saw a notable boost in shares over the holiday weekend whereas retail stores saw a small dip. This trend shows that mobile shopping will have a larger part in these sales events in the future.</p>
  <p>Online only stores such as Newegg, Tiger-direct, and NCIX got in on the holiday action as well. Newegg, which boasted a Black November event, had deals lined up all month. Collaborating with other companies allowed Newegg to offer the best deals in tech on the internet to-date. NCIX utilized the popular video platform, YouTube, to reach hundreds of thousands of customers in one of the cheapest and most successful marketing pushes in US history. Don’t forget to leave a comment below.</p>
  <style>
  .element{
     shape-outside: url(images/cybermonday.png);
     shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
     float: left;
   margin: 10px;
  }
  </style>
 </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <text>Contact Us:</text><br>
  <a href="mailto: gshepherd252@gmail.com">E-mail</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

Unless you need the paragraph ID for some reason, I would suggest changing it to a class, so it can be reused.

Then, to add padding to the paragraph class you can do something like this:

```
.paragraph {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

To create two columns you need to do a few things. I'd suggest wrapping the contents of each column in a new div, with a class of col-50 (as you want each to take up 50% of the container). Like this...

```
<main>
   <div class="col-50">
     <div class="paragraph">
       ..contents here
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-50">
     <div class="paragraph">
       ..contents here
     </div>
   </div>
</main>
```

You will need to add some rules to the new columns and to the main container.

```
.col-50 {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

main:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

and the footer too..

```
footer {
   clear: both
}
```

If the columns are not showing side by side, you can reduce their width, as padding can affect this (look into box-sizing rule)

You can see a simplified demo of your content here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/rWJyEm

Note that I've also moved your style for .element to the css.

Comment: Fantastic, I am going to modify this a bit to make the side column width shorter. and adding an image to the article. Thank you for the help, going to study what you did here to figure out where I went wrong.!!